# Showing specific percentage disc

Tags: hard-drive

I need to show only disc that has specific percentage used like for example 50% of space taken appears but disc that have 33% will not appear.
Now i know the command df -h but i don't know how to specify the percentage.
Is there a way to do it in terminal or do I need to write a script for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` to simplify the output of just about any command.

Well, if you want to *only* show the ones with 50% or even 5*% like 55% you can use grep like so:

```
df -h | grep "50%"
```

or to show all 50 some percent like 51 or 55 as well, you can run this:

```
df -h | grep "5.%"
```

To show anything *greater than or equal to* 50%, run this instead:

```
df -h | egrep "10.%|9.%|8.%|7.%|6.%|5.%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do a *numeric* comparison rather than a lexical one, I'd suggest using something like `perl` or `awk` e.g.

```
df -h | awk 'NR==1 || substr($5,1,length($5)-1) > 33'
```

where

- `NR==1` always print the header line
- `substr($5,1,length($5)-1)` remove the trailing `%` sign from the 5th field
- numerically compare the result to the value `33`

To make it more flexible, you could pass the desired cutoff value in as a variable e.g.

```
df -h | awk -v val=33 'NR==1 || substr($5,1,length($5)-1) > val'
```